# How to import modules in deep directories in Rust?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a file in `src/user/entity/user.rs` with the following code:

```
pub struct User {
  name: String,
  email: String,
  age: i32,
  is_active: bool,
}

impl User {
  pub fn new(name: String, email: String, age: i32, is_active: bool) -> User {
    User {
      name,
      email,
      age,
      is_active
    }
  }

  pub fn get_name(&self) -> &str {
    &self.name
  }

  pub fn get_email(&self) -> &str {
    &self.email 
  }

  pub fn get_age(&self) -> i32 {
    self.age
  }

  pub fn is_active(&self) -> bool {
    self.is_active
  }

  pub fn set_name(&mut self, name: String) {
    self.name = name
  }

  pub fn set_email(&mut self, email: String) {
    self.email = email
  }

  pub fn set_age(&mut self, age: i32) {
    self.age = age
  }

  pub fn set_active(&mut self, is_active: bool) {
    self.is_active = is_active
  }
}
```

How do I import this into the `src/main.rs` file?

```
use user::entity::User;

fn main() {
  let mut _user = User::new("John".to_string(), "j@j.com".to_string(), 30, true);

  println!("User");
  println!("Name: {}", _user.get_name());
  println!("Email: {}", _user.get_email());
  println!("Age: {}", _user.get_age());
  println!("Active: {}", _user.is_active());

  _user.set_active(false);
  _user.set_name("Jane".to_string());
  _user.set_email("j@j2.com".to_string());
  _user.set_age(43);

}
```

Do I have to create any more files? Do I have to put something in cargo.toml? I've read the official documentation but I still don't understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a module for each level.

The *good* way to do this is to put in `main.rs`:

```rust
pub mod user;
```

Then create a file `src/user/mod.rs` or `src/user.rs` and put in it:

```rust
pub mod entity;
```

Then create a file `src/user/entity/mod.rs` or `src/user/entity.rs` and put in it:

```rust
pub mod user;
```

Then change the `use` declaration at the top of `main.rs` to:

```rust
use user::entity::user::User;
```

Then your code should work.

The *quick-and-dirty* (and bad) way is to put in `main.rs`:

```rust
pub mod user {
    pub mod entity {
        pub mod user;
    }
}
```

And change the `use` declaration as above, and you're done.

Comment: It worked!!! Thanks a lot for the help!
A doubt, is there any way to not need to create a mod.rs file in each folder?

and a way to make the structure shorter:pub mod user {
  pub mod entity {
      pub mod user;
  }
}

Comment: @AbnerMatheus There is the quick-and-dirty (and bad) way :) But if your really need the file to be at `user/entity/user/`, then there's probably more stuff under `user/` and `user/entity/` so the `mod.rs` make more sense. If not, then you're probably structuring your modules wrong.